# jQuery: how do I create a toggle between two stylesheets?

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have two CSS stylesheets, how do I toggle between them using a single onclick  element?

The elements would be:

- stylesheet_a.css
- stylesheet_b.css
- a DIV element with ID of "css_toggle"

Comment: Look over here: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/styleswitch/toggle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general idea:

1. Bind a `click()` event to `css_toggle` - `$('#css_toggle').click(event_handler);`
2. Within the event handler, change the `src` attribute of your stylesheet

More detail and code can be found in the following tutorial - http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/switch-css-stylesheets-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

Say you have these elements:

```
<link id=a rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet_a.css" type="text/css">
<link id=b rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet_b.css" type="text/css" disabled>
```

If you will add this script:

```
$("#css_toggle").click(function() {
  var isOff = $("a").get(0).disabled;
  $("a").get(0).disabled = !isOff;
  $("b").get(0).disabled = isOff;
});
```

it should do what you want. Not tested, but idea should be clear.

Comment: have you tested this across browsers? i dont think `disabled` is a standard attribute.